# Label in Listview changes Height and Width after scrolling

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a Listview with a Label. If I scroll down and up again the Label has other Height and Width. Even tho some Labels seem to remain stable.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this, so all Labels remain at their original size?

ListView:

```xml
<ListView
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    SeparatorVisibility="None"
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
    <ListView.Behaviors>
        <b:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="ItemTapped"
            Command="{Binding ContactTappedCommand}"
            EventArgsParameterPath="Item"/>
    </ListView.Behaviors>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame
                    Style="{StaticResource ListViewEintrag}">
                    <Grid 
                        Style="{StaticResource ListViewGrid}"
                        RowDefinitions="{StaticResource RowDefinition}"
                        ColumnDefinitions="{StaticResource ColumnDefinition}">
                        <local:CustomLabel
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            LetterSpacing="0.15"
                            Style="{StaticResource Name}"
                            Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <local:CustomLabel
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            TextColor="#33A028"
                            Style="{StaticResource Info}"
                            Text="{Binding TotalCredits, Converter={StaticResource DecimalToCurrency}}"/>
                        <local:CustomLabel
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            TextColor="#BC2F36"
                            Style="{StaticResource Info}"
                            Text="{Binding TotalDebts, Converter={StaticResource DecimalToCurrency}}"/>
                        <local:CustomLabel
                            LetterSpacing="0.1"
                            Grid.RowSpan="3"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontSize="18"
                            Margin="10,0"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource Bliss2-Bold}"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                            TextColor="{Binding Color}"
                            Text="{Binding AbsSaldo, Converter={StaticResource DecimalToCurrency}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ColumnDefinition:

```xml
<ColumnDefinitionCollection x:Key="ColumnDefinition">
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</ColumnDefinitionCollection>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could this have something to do with the cachingstrategy you're using on the ListView? What happens if you get rid of CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"? Also, what's custom about your CustomLabel?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add your `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` and `Grid.RowDefinitions`? My guess is that you're using `Auto` and the problem could potentially be solved by using `Star` or `Absolute`: https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin#rows-and-columns

Comment: @BrandonMinnick, I have edited the Question. What do you recommend using here?

Comment: @MaxHampton This ChachingStrategy is needed, because if im not using this some ListView Entries might get empty if I am scrolling.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick Oh, I feel so stupid. Just edited Auto in * and now it works perfectly. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome, @AlexanderEndler! To help devs with the same question in the future, double check my answer below, and, if it's correct, make sure to mark it as answered 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `ColumnDefinitions`, use `*` instead of `Auto` to avoid dynamic resizing.

```xml
<ColumnDefinitionCollection x:Key="ColumnDefinition">
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</ColumnDefinitionCollection>
```